# Database Files through Linked Servers

Tags: sql-server-2014, linked-server

Is there another way to create a script that I can see all database files with their disk space details across databases and across servers?

I can do it through Registered Servers.

But I want to know if I can do it using 1 instance with linked servers for all the servers. My idea is to generate a script that will read each database for each linked server then when I have all the data, it can now be passed to the SQL Server Job.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Powershell is the way. And it make it easier, just install dbatools on one of your admin servers and use [`get-dbadiskspace`](https://dbatools.io/functions/get-dbadiskspace/)

> **Get-DbaDiskSpace -ComputerName server1, server2, server3 -Unit GB**

if you have list of servers then you can use

```
$servers = get-content "D:\serverlist.txt"
foreach ($server in $servers) {
  Get-DbaDiskSpace -ComputerName $server -Unit GB
}
```

You can even dump the above info using [invoke-sqlcmd2](https://dbatools.io/functions/invoke-sqlcmd2/) into a central db for reporting .

Answer (score 1):

You can get your list of linked servers from the [sys.servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-servers-transact-sql) view. Then you can use a [cursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql) to go through the list and generate [dynamic sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) to execute against each server.

Below is an example retrieving multiple database properties from all linked servers.

```
declare @servername varchar(255)
declare @sql nvarchar(4000)

DECLARE c_databases CURSOR 
FOR    
SELECT  name FROM  sys.servers where is_linked = 1
-- Open the cursor.
OPEN c_databases 
-- Loop through the partitions.
WHILE (1=1) 
BEGIN    
        FETCH NEXT FROM c_databases        
        INTO @servername

        IF @@FETCH_STATUS < 0 
        BREAK 

                set @sql = N'
                select d.database_id,d.name as databasename,sp.name as owner,d.compatibility_level,cast(round(sum(mf.Size)/128,0) as float) as size,d.collation_name, d.user_access_desc,d.recovery_model_desc,d.is_read_only 
                From ['+@servername+'].master.sys.databases d
                inner join ['+@servername+'].master.sys.server_principals sp
                on d.owner_sid = sp.sid
                inner join ['+@servername+'].master.sys.master_files mf
                on d.database_id = mf.database_id
                where d.database_id <> 2
                group by d.database_id,d.name,sp.name,d.compatibility_level,d.collation_name, d.user_access_desc,d.recovery_model_desc,d.is_read_only,d.state'

                --print @sql
                EXEC sp_executesql @sql

END

CLOSE c_databases
DEALLOCATE c_databases 
GO
```